# CSS and JS Files Not Found Magento

Tags: php, magento2.3

**Magento CSS and JS** files are not found.

I have just installed **Magento 2.3**, The issue is that the JS and CSS files are not located at what they are supposed to be and because of that i am getting not found error when access Magento admin panel,

Here is the screenshot shot:

[image]

I also have checked the directory like **require js** which is empty,

Here is the screenshot shot:

[image]

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens after you run **`setup:upgrade command`**

In order to fix it, you have to deploy the **static view files** of your Magento shop by running below command:

**`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`**

Note: **`-f`** to force static deployment when in developer mode

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked brilliantly. Question is what it do and why magento does not do this itself during its  installation?

Comment: If you are in **Production mode** static files are not generated or cached.But Magento allows developer to write or add static / custom static files to the Magento file system when your Magento shop is set for production mode., like a custom css and js.